# Getting User's State with CoreLocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am using CoreLocation to get a user's latitude and longitude coordinates. Is there a simple or standardized way to get the user's state prefix? For example, if the user launched the app from California, I would get CA? I would prefer not to use a third party application that I need to send the geo-coordinates to. It would be great if I could just create a method like the one I am using to get the latitude below.

```
- (NSString *)getUserLatitude
{
NSString *userLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
return userLatitude;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the reverse geocoding feature of [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Specifically you need to use the method `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:` that will return to your completionHandler a `CLPlacemark` object.

Such object will have many user-friendly geographical information and you may want to use its `administrativeArea` property which, according to the doc, will contain what you're looking for, if available.

> **administrativeArea**
>
> The state or province associated with the
>   placemark. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *administrativeArea
>
> **Discussion**
>   If the placemark location is Apple’s headquarters, for example, the
>   value for this property would be the string “CA” or “California”.